# How To exclude a Folder from 301 Redirect .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a 301 redirect on the domain goodereader.com that points to goodereader.com/blog/

I wanted to setup a forum, and wanted to exclude /forum/ from being 301'd

Here my current .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/.*$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.goodereader\.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://goodereader.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^goodereader\.com$

RewriteRule (.*) http://goodereader.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ blog [L]

<IfModule mod_security.c>

SecFilterEngine Off

SecFilterScanPOST Off

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I think you need to repeat the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/.*$` line before the second `RewriteRule` statement.

Comment: I tried this, does not work.

Comment: You may need to clear your browser's cache.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, you can fix this by adding the same condition to the 2nd rule. Rewrite conditions only get applied to the *immediately* following rule, they're not global in any way.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.goodereader\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://goodereader.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forum/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^goodereader\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://goodereader.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ blog [L]
```

or use a pass through:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^forum/ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.goodereader\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://goodereader.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^goodereader\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://goodereader.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^$ blog [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser's cache. 301 redirects are permanent and the browser will always cache them.

Comment: I think its working. I opened up http://goodereader.com/forum/ and its resolving to a 404 now, which is good, because forum software is not installed yet, but its now working for me. Can anyone else confirm?